# How to indicate that an xml schema that requires schema 1.1 features?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

If I create an XML Schema that requires schema 1.1 features (especially subtle ones, like removing an optional element in restriction of a base type), what is the best way to indicate that this schema should not be used with a processor that only understands version 1.0?

In an XSLT stylesheet file, it is possible to indicate the version of the XSLT specification that is used using a `version` attribute.

But in an XSD file, the `version` attribute does not have this meaning - it is a free-form attribute that says something about the version of the schema, not about the version of the specification that is being used.

And is it *required* to label a schema that uses 1.1 features?

I have a complex set of schemas using the FPML 5.5 specification and some custom schemas, and it cannot be validated with some schema validators, but I'm not sure if that is because the validator has bugs or because the schema is subtly using xml schema 1.1 features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At this point in time, this issue is not that easy to resolve; this is because most of the XSD processors are 1.0, and the schema versioning introduced in XSD 1.1 spec can't apply backwards. To learn more about it (in general) have a look at [The Schema Versioning Namepsace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#vc-namespace), and the examples included in section [4.2.2 Conditional inclusion](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cip).

You could implement your own pre-processing solution, that is to at least help with choosing the appropriate XSD processor using something such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning">

    <xsd:element name="e" vc:minVersion="1.1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="a" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="b" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>       
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="e" vc:minVersion="1.0" vc:maxVersion="1.1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="a" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="b" />            
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>      
</xsd:schema>
```

This way at least you'll be using an XSD 1.1 endorsed approach to versioning; it also comes with a processing model. For certain tasks, it is relatively easy to build a pre-processor that at least will handle the appropriate selection of the XSD processor (1.0 or 1.1) . To make simpler in a closed environment, you could also choose a convention where you could mark the whole `xsd:schema` with vc:minVersion="1.1" - basically what you seem to have wanted to begin with.

Regarding your last paragraph, the choice of the XSD processor has to be asserted rather than implied. This is because XSD 1.1 allows for constructs that were impossible in XSD 1.0 (e.g. an `all` compositor containing particles with max occurrence greater than 1)... so unless one makes a prior decision re: the processor to use, the XSD may or may not be invalid. Whereas other things will be invalid regardless of the processor used.

Comment: Is it also legal to put a vc:minVersion="1.1" on the `<schema>` element itself? That would at least be a clear indicator for visual inspection, even if XSD 1.0-only processors don't understand it

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is legal, hence my recommendation.

Answer (score 9):

There was a discussion related to this on the XML Schema dev list:
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2013Sep/0000.html

And the conclusion was that we should use the vc:minVersion and vc:maxVersion attributes on the xsd:schema element if we want to specify the version of the XML Schema.
The attributes are not in the schema namespace, they are in the "http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" namespace. So, you can set them also on an XML Schema version 1.0, and this schema will be valid.

So, if you want to specify if a schema is version 1.0, you can set the version attributes on the xsd:schema element like this: vc:minVersion="1.0" vc:maxVersion="1.1" (minVersion is inclusive, maxVersion is exclusive).

If you want to set the schema version to 1.1, you can set the version attributes on the xsd:schema element like this: vc:minVersion="1.1". The maxVersion attribute doesn't need to be set in this case because we don't have yet XML Schema versions grater that 1.1.