# XSD 1.1 - Invalid content was found starting with with element 'xs:alternative'

Tags: xml, xsd, phpstorm, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

In my XSD, I'm trying to use `alternative` tag. For some reasons, I got this error in my IDE (PHPStorm) :

> Invalid content was starting with with element 'xs:alternative' ...

**XSD**

```
<xs:complexType name="tableType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="columnType" name="column" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element type="keyType" name="key" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:alternative test="@type='index'" type="keyIndexType"/>
            <xs:alternative test="@type='unique'" type="KeyUniqueType"/>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

I saw [I should not add something more to use the 1.1 xsd version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591612/how-to-declare-i-want-to-use-xml-schema-1-1) but do I need something to support `alternative` tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSD processor must support **XSD *1.1*** in order to use `xs:alternative` ([**Conditional Type Assignment**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)).  An **XSD *1.0*** processor will not allow `xs:alternative` as a child of `xs:element` and will provide an error message such as the one you received.  Therefore, you can conclude that your XSD processor only supports **XSD 1.0**.

For a working example of CTA, see [How to make type depend on attribute value using Conditional Type Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878402/290085) (but, of course, this too requires **XSD 1.1**).

Comment: In my case, the XSD processor is linked to PHPStorm ?

Comment: Yes.  You can try [configuring PHPStorm for XSD 1.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/validating-web-content-files.html), but you may find that such configuration only allows you to validate a XSD 1.1 document itself against the XSD 1.1 schema of schemas; it may not actually invoke a XSD 1.1 processor to enable XSD 1.1 validation against instance XML documents.  Perhaps a PHPStorm user or JetBrains employee could say for sure.

Answer (score 5):

I found my solution thanks to @kjhughes.
I had to switch from XSD 1.0 processor to XSD 1.1 processor.

In PHPstorm : Settings panel > Languages & Frameworks > Default XML Shemas

[image]

> Notice : after to 'Apply' changes, **you must restart PHPStorm**.

Comment: Thx. The same works for PyCharm.